# How to make every widget in ListView.builder the same height

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-listview

I have a list of widgets with different height. When i put the list into a ListView.builder, each widget takes only the height of the content. But i want each widget to be as high as the highest widget in the list (see image). How can i achieve this?

(ignore the padding/alignment in my image. Its only about the height)
[image]

My list contains this widget:

```dart
class CustomListTile extends StatelessWidget {
  const CustomListTile({
    super.key,
    required this.label,
    this.statusIcon,
    this.trailing,
  });

  final String label;
  final IconData? statusIcon;
  final Widget? trailing;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Text(
                  label,
                  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                ),
                if (statusIcon != null)
                  Icon(
                    statusIcon,
                  ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          if (trailing != null) trailing!,
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, Flutter doesn't have the easy way you can archive this, you cannot know height of widget unless it was built

You can try this way, I assume that you have a list of `yourModels` and you want to build a `ListView` from `yourModels` by `_yourItemWidget`:

```
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final yourModels = List<Object>.filled(5, 0, growable: true);

    double maxHeight = 0;
    final List<Widget> widgets = yourModels.map((model) {
      final widget = _yourItemWidget();
      final measureHeight = MeasureUtil.measureWidget(widget).height;

      if (maxHeight < measureHeight) {
        maxHeight = measureHeight;
      }
      return widget;
    }).toList();

    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
            child: ListView.builder(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return SizedBox(
              height: maxHeight,
              child: widgets[index],
            );
          },
          itemCount: widgets.length,
        )),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _yourItemWidget() {
    final random = Random();
    final height = Random().nextInt(100).toDouble();

    return Container(
      color: Color.fromRGBO(
        random.nextInt(255),
        random.nextInt(255),
        random.nextInt(255),
        1,
      ),
      width: 100,
      height: height,
    );
  }
}
```

MeasureUtil is the class that help you calculate the Size of widget:

```
class MeasureUtil {
  static Size measureWidget(Widget widget, [BoxConstraints constraints = const BoxConstraints()]) {
    final PipelineOwner pipelineOwner = PipelineOwner();
    final _MeasurementView rootView = pipelineOwner.rootNode = _MeasurementView(constraints);
    final BuildOwner buildOwner = BuildOwner(focusManager: FocusManager());
    final RenderObjectToWidgetElement<RenderBox> element = RenderObjectToWidgetAdapter<RenderBox>(
      container: rootView,
      debugShortDescription: '[root]',
      child: widget,
    ).attachToRenderTree(buildOwner);
    try {
      rootView.scheduleInitialLayout();
      pipelineOwner.flushLayout();
      return rootView.size;
    } finally {
      // Clean up.
      element.update(RenderObjectToWidgetAdapter<RenderBox>(container: rootView));
      buildOwner.finalizeTree();
    }
  }
}

class _MeasurementView extends RenderBox with RenderObjectWithChildMixin<RenderBox> {
  final BoxConstraints boxConstraints;

  _MeasurementView(this.boxConstraints);

  @override
  void performLayout() {
    assert(child != null);
    child!.layout(boxConstraints, parentUsesSize: true);
    size = child!.size;
  }

  @override
  void debugAssertDoesMeetConstraints() => true;
}
```

Comment: Your example works fine, but when i use my widget list instead of containers with fixed height, then i got multiple error. I solved the Directionality error with the textDirection Attribute but there are many other error with constraints etc. I added my Widget to the question. Do you know how can i get this to work? My widget has no fixed size